# URL Extension in MVC 4 Not working after update

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I've just updated my MVC 3 to MVC 4

However now my URL extension methods are not binding. It does not seems to think Url has the method `PSUrl()`. They are still in the same name space..

Method:

```
public static string PSUrl(this UrlHelper url)
```

View:

```
@Url.PSUrl()
```

Does MVC4 have a different way of extending? I cant seem to find anything on it.

Comment: Extension methods still work exactly the same. Double check all your namespaces and that the correct ones are being referenced.

Comment: Extension methods have nothing to do with MVC versions.

Comment: @JonathanWood Thanks for clarifying. I will have to double check it all in the morning. Its an old project so maybe I've missed something. :)

Answer (score 0):

The updates must have removed a name space from my views `web.config` (Note: there are two web.configs, check the one inside the Views folder!)

Re-adding the line to use my extensions, resolves it again.

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="MyProject.Extensions" />
```